# sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres when using flask to access Heroku postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've seen similar questions asked and the answer is typically to simply change "postgres" to "postgresql" in the database URL. However, I still see this error.

In app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = setup_db(app)

def get_times():
  date=request.get_json()[:10]
  raw_date_data = OpenAppointments.query.filter_by(date=date).first()
  ...
```

In models.py:

```
from decouple import config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
def setup_db(app):
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = config('DATABASE_URL')
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
    return db

class OpenAppointments(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'open_appointments'
  date = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
  time_1 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
  time_2 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
  time_3 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
  time_4 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
  time_5 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
  time_6 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)

  def __init__(self, date, time_1, time_2, time_3, time_4, time_5, time_6):
    self.date = date
    self.time_1 = time_1
    self.time_2 = time_2
    self.time_3 = time_3
    self.time_4 = time_4
    self.time_5 = time_5
    self.time_6 = time_6

  def insert(self):
      db.session.add(self)
      db.session.commit()
  def delete(self):
      db.session.delete(self)
      db.session.commit()
  def update(self):
      db.session.commit()
```

And finally, the .env:

```
DATABASE_URL = postgresql://iuifkgiqsykklf:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxdb5a6125844793db8dc1623f43dce7de6889eb256@ec2-54-156-110-139.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfbcrvv8dikopj
```

UPDATE:

I've updated the imports on models.py. Also, I tried importing os and using os.environ.get instead of config but I get the same error.

UPDATE 2:

I should mention I did not have python-dotenv installed but when I did install it I got the same error. Here is the updated code for models.py:

```
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def setup_db(app):
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
    return db

class OpenAppointments(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'open_appointments'
  date = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
  time_1 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
  time_2 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
  time_3 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
  time_4 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
  time_5 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
  time_6 = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)

  def __init__(self, date, time_1, time_2, time_3, time_4, time_5, time_6):
    self.date = date
    self.time_1 = time_1
    self.time_2 = time_2
    self.time_3 = time_3
    self.time_4 = time_4
    self.time_5 = time_5
    self.time_6 = time_6

  def insert(self):
      db.session.add(self)
      db.session.commit()
  def delete(self):
      db.session.delete(self)
      db.session.commit()
  def update(self):
      db.session.commit()
```

When I print out the variable for both os and config, for some reason it drops the "ql":

```
print(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
print(config('DATABASE_URL'))
```

yields:

```
2022-02-07T17:36:36.227545+00:00 app[web.1]: postgres://iuifkgiqsykklf:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd40a28adb5a6125844793db8dc1623f43dce7de6889eb256@ec2-54-156-110-139.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfbcrvv8dikopj
2022-02-07T17:36:36.227840+00:00 app[web.1]: postgres://iuifkgiqsykklf:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd40a28adb5a6125844793db8dc1623f43dce7de6889eb256@ec2-54-156-110-139.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfbcrvv8dikopj
```

Comment: Do you have `python-dotenv` installed? Where is the `config` in `config('DATABASE_URL')` coming from? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: What if you do: `import os` and then `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")`

Comment: Thanks for replying, I made an update with all relevant info.

Comment: No you haven't. You have not answered; "Where is the config in config('DATABASE_URL') coming from?".  You have also not shown your `os.environ.get()` code.  While you are updating, show the output of `os.environ.get()` as well as `config('DATABASE_URL')` e.g throw in a `print(config('DATABASE_URL'))`, etc.

Comment: In my update I mentioned that the imports had been added, which is where config is used. It comes from the decouple module. I said I replaced config with os.environ.get, so I didn't see a reason to post it. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: To make this work you will need to settle on either `decouple` or `dotenv`. The you are getting `postgres` instead of `postgresql` indicates you are probably in the wrong environment when running the app. In other words one that in `.env` has `DATABASE_URL = postgres:// ...`

Answer (score 0):

`DATABASE_URL` is a "system" environment variable provided by Heroku, it overrides the one in your .env. You need to replace `postgres` by `postgresql` programmatically.